# Using Dreamweaver to manage Heroku?

Tags: facebook, heroku, dreamweaver

First the question: Does anyone know how to setup a Dreamweaver site to connect/manage a Heroku site?

I'm sure some of you have seen that Facebook apps can be hosted for free through Heroku -- however, for some reason the Git cloning doesn't work on my PC. It works fine on my Mac but I've gone through dozens of forums looking for a solution (something jacked up with my SSH key).

On top of that, I despise command-line stuff and am very familiar with Dreamweaver, so I'd prefer to manage my Heroku site through Dreamweaver if possible.

Would love any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Dreamweaver supports Git out of the box, but there are extensions available.

Without Git working with Heroku, you're going to get nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out.
https://github.com/ChrisMcKee/gitweaver
This is dependent on TortoiseGIT, so it won't help you if you are using Dreamweaver on a Mac, but for your Windows machine it should be fine.